# Facebook: How to avoid getting duplicates from a FB Graph Request?

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a FB Graph Request to get updates from a user's Open Graph. I only want to query for new objects, and not retrieve the ones that have already been retrieved. Is there a way to filter out objects that have already been retrieved?

If there's something like a "Stop searching at ID#: x" function in the graph API request that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with timestamps or date strings by storing the most recent created_time of the objects you have retrieved.  Then, you could do this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/photos?since=1419125506`

or

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/photos?since=2014-12-29T16:29:45+0000`

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty using time-based pagination. The GET request is valid in the API Explorer, but the return doesn't look to have been changed. I'm trying : me/music.listens?since=1419125506

Comment: Appears as if this is only available when querying for connections, like feed, photos, etc. Not for a user action

Answer (score 0):

You must think if this is really what you want, if you will query something like /feed but will continue every time from the last timestamp you won't be able to update the old objects.

In this case the objects are posts and there number of likes/comments won't be the same evert day.

If you store you data in a db just clear it before new feed will be inserted.